# Makefile: fatal error: NE10.h: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, cmake, neon

Currently trying to Makefile and encountered this error:

```
fatal error: NE10.h: No such file or directory
#include "NE10.h"
         ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

Am looking for the cause of this (is it related to the root directory?) and possible resolution of such an error?

Currently on a NVIDIA Xavier Arm Processor.

And

```
command -v g++
/usr/bin/g++

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
```

Comment: Read about how C preprocessor works, and how it handles includes/include directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by doing an install of the NE10 package, then including in cmake/make process.

```
https://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/
```

Was missing the package on the whole, for anyone looking for this answer. Thanks!